# Work done on a charged particle

Tags: electrostatics, energy, charge, work

Suppose we have a stationary configuration of source charges and we want to move a test charge $q$ from point $a$ to point $b$. How much work will we have to do? Since the force on $q$ is $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$, the minimum force that we must exert must be $-\vec{F}$, which will do the job.

As $\mathbf F_{net}=0, \quad ∆KE = 0$

However, the conservative force $F$ will be responsible for changing the potential energy of the charged particle $Q$. Thus, $$\mathbf W_c = \int \mathbf F\cdot dr = \int \mathbf -F_{me}\cdot dr = -\Delta U.$$

My doubt is, since potential energy is changing, and change in kinetic energy is zero, total energy changes ($∆E=∆U$). And we know that is only possible if some non-conservative force is acting on $Q$, taking energy out of it. (which equals $∆U$)

What is this non-conservative force here and how is energy being dissipated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dilemma is resolved if you start by defining the system under consideration.

System - test charge $Q$ only

Net force on charge is the sum of the external force due to you and external force due to the charges.
These two external forces are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction so, indeed, the net force of the charge is zero and the net work don on the charge is zero and the charge in kinetic energy of the charge is zero.
Why have I not mentioned the electric potential energy of the charge?
It is because the system under consideration is a single charge and for the concept of electric potential energy to be used the system must have at least two charges.

System - test charge $Q$ and all the other charges present.

The only external force is the force due to you.
All other forces within the system are internal Newton third law pairs, equal magnitude and opposite in direction.
The force that you exert on the system does work on the system of charges and the electric potential energy of the system of all the charges changes due to you doing work on the system.

Comment: So that means there will be a change in KE of the whole system as well as change in the PE of the whole system keeping the total energy of the system constant. But I have one more doubt. The work done by my force is on the test charge Q so shouldn't Q be the system or is it still possible to choose the system of all the charges, even if $F_{me}$ is acting on one *part* of the system, i.e Q.

Comment: The test charge has two forces acting on it with a net force of zero and hence its KE will not change. If all the other charges are not allowed to move then the work you do changes the electric potential energy of the system of all the charges.

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy of a single charge has no meaning.
It is always a potential energy of a system (two bodies minimum).

For a single charge case the assumption is that the other charge is at infinity.

So if you consider the system of two charges only force acting on it is $F_{ext}$ and it will do a work, this work will be stored in the potential energy of the system   and kinetic energy of individual components of the system (ie zero in our case).

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is, since potential energy is changing, and change in kinetic
> energy is zero, total energy changes ($∆E=∆U$). And we know that is
> only possible if some non-conservative force is acting on $Q$, taking
> energy out of it. (which equals $∆U$)

It is incorrect to assume the charge can only lose energy to a non-conservative force. The difference between the conservative force and the non-conservative force is what happens to the energy that's removed from the charge. The negative work done by the conservative force of the electric field stores the energy in the form of electrical potential energy of the system of charges. The negative work done by a non-conservative force dissipates that energy, as in the case of negative work done on charge to overcome electrical resistance, dissipating the energy as heat.

Hope this helps.